# Get current UIViewController from UIButton's class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have custom UIButton which programmatically interacts (triggers) with ViewController methods via protocol. But the behaviour of the button has to be dependent on the ViewController placed on. I do this to minimise amount of code in ViewControllers itself, as the button has to remain the same and bear the same functions (navigation).
Is there any way in UIButton's custom class to get the ViewController it is placed on?

Comment: That's not what you want to do. Instead, add properties to the button class. Then each view controller can set the properties as appropriate. The button should not know anything about any view controller.

Comment: The key idea is not to write code in VC at all. In your case, I have to rewrite VC classes, although, its OK to rewrite only one class (as custom behaviour required only once) the problem is here: the button is being placed on storyboard, no any connection programmatically except protocol. So, if I have only one VC requiring custom behaviour, how to access the button from VC side?

Comment: A VC has access to its views through outlets or properties. In MVC, a view should never know about its controller.

Comment: From this point of view, is my custom UIButton a controller or its strictly a view? It creates and hides some buttons programmatically. That buttons trigger actions on the appropriate VCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow @rmaddy advice in a specific way, borrowing from the SDK's style

```
// MyCutomButton.h
@protocol MyCustomButtonDatasource;

@interface MyCustomButton : UIButton
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet id<MyCustomButtonDatasource>datasource;
// etc
@end

@protocol MyCustomButtonDatasource <NSObject>
@optional
- (NSString *)howShouldIBehave:(MyCustomButton *)button;
@end
```

Now the button can have it's datasource set in IB.  View controllers that include it will need a little additional code (sorry, it's unavoidable in a good design).  They will declare themselves as implementing MyCustomButtonDatasource.

When MyCustomButton needs to behave conditionally based on where it's placed, it can ask its datasource...

```
// MyCustomButton.m

NSString *string = @"defaultBehavior";  // per @RichardTopchiy's suggestion
if ([self.datasource respondsToSelector:@selector(howShouldIBehave:)])
    string = [self.datasource howShouldIBehave:self];

// string is just made-up here, have it answer something simple (int, BOOL)
// that lets the button proceed with the right behavior.  Don't ask for
// anything that relies on specific knowledge of how MyCustomButton
// is implemented
```

**EDIT** - To create the relationship, if you've decorated the property as an IBOutlet (as shown above), you should be able to setup the relationship in IB.  Declare your view controller as implementing `<MyCustomButtonDatasource>`.  Select your custom button, then the connections inspector, then drag to your view controller.

Alternatively, make the button itself an IBOutlet property in the view controller and, in viewDidLoad, do:

```
self.customButton.datasource = self;
```

The last way to do it is give your button a tag, say, 128, then:

```
MyCustomButton *customButton = (MyCustomButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:128];
self.customButton.datasource = self;
```

Comment: Is it good practice to include the method as "optional" and implement only on VC that should use non-default behaviour?

Comment: One more question, from the VC-side - how should I bind `howShouldIBehave` method to ViewController? Do I need to create a new instance of CustomButton (I think no) or just "grab" existing button. I need this to set the delegate.