# iOS: Get 'UIViewController' of 'UIButton'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I need to get a reference (object) of `UIViewController` in sub class of `UIButton`. Here I've tried something but failed.

```
class NavigationBarButton: UIButton {


    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        var viewController: UIViewController? {
            var nextResponder: UIResponder? = self
            repeat {
                nextResponder = nextResponder?.next

                if let viewController = nextResponder as? UIViewController {
                    return viewController
                }

            } while nextResponder != nil

            return nil
        }

        guard let vcViewController = self.viewController else { print("NavigationBarButton view controller could not found"); return }

        print("handle further operations with ViewController of Button")

    }

}

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NavigationBarButton?


}
```

> **Result:**
>   NavigationBarButton view controller could not found

Is there any other way, without updating UIViewController, I can get view controller reference in sub class of UIButton. Any other UIButton method can help me here, where I can get view controller of button.

Similar SO Que. but not useful for this issue: [Get current UIViewController from UIButton's class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145178/get-current-uiviewcontroller-from-uibuttons-class)

Comment: Why do you need the `UIViewController` instance in the first place? A button should not know about which VC it is in. This seems to be bad design.

Comment: @Sweeper - I need to to write some generic code (implement some attributes and actions for view controller) inside button class and that requires view controller reference.

Comment: This can break very easily, there is no good reason for doing such a thing. I also suppose that you are trying to access view controller from a button inside `UINavigationItem` and that's even a bigger problem because the button will be inside the navigation controller, not inside your controller. Not even speaking about the fact that the navigation bar hierarchy is a bit complicated. Maybe it would be easier to access `view.window.rootVieController` and search `children` for the controller you want. Using `didMoveToWindow` instead of `didMoveToSuperview` should be the first step anyway.

Comment: @Sulthan - I've not used default navigation bar or UINavigationItem class. It just a button class name like NavigationBarButton but it extends to UIButton and located inside UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
class NavigationBarButton: UIButton {


    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()

        var viewController: UIViewController? {
            var nextResponder: UIResponder? = self
            repeat {
                nextResponder = nextResponder?.next

                if let viewController = nextResponder as? UIViewController {
                    return viewController
                }

            } while nextResponder != nil

            return nil
        }

        guard let vcViewController = self.viewController else { print("NavigationBarButton view controller could not found"); return }

        print("handle further operations with ViewController of Button")

    }

}

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NavigationBarButton?


}
```